# Звук при нажатии на Button

Tags: objective-c, xcode, button, аудио

Подскажите, как можно добавить звук при нажатии на Button и при завершении отсчета времени?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SystemSoundID clickSound;

AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(
CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), CFSTR("click"), CFSTR("wav"), NULL), &clickSound);
```

---

Метод экшена

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(clickSound);
```

Comment: не много не понял, где нужно применять, в самом экшене `ButtonPressed` или до этого создать и потом применить?

Comment: @david-kakaladze


`-(IBAction)твояКнопка:(id)sender {
...
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(clickSound);
...
}`

Comment: чет все-равно ругается... а `#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>` надо?

Comment: @david-kakaladze покажи список ошибок

Comment: [вот](http://s013.radikal.ru/i323/1512/da/9fff6c84b4a5.png), понимаю, что-то делаю не так, но не знаю что именно

Comment: @david-kakaladze #import <AVFoundation / AVAudioPlayer.h>

Comment: Импорт класса тоже сделал... может там еще что-то прикрутить надо?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33294/discussion-between-ddevil-and-david-kakaladze).